# MDL Tab loading Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my website ([Link](https://qualexcraft.tk/about)), (running MDL by Google) I have an annoying issue where you can see the #harule tab for a little bit before it vanishes. That tab does not have the property `is-active`, and should be hidden on the page, until you click on the `harule` tab. Is there any fix for this, whether it be MDL or normal HTML, CSS, JS?

Extra Info: Each person has their own file inside /about/allPeople. Try /about/allPeople/qualexgaming.php. These files are then included from the /about/index.php file.

Comment: it is because the tab is constructed on page ready , but the elements are created are while page render .

Comment: what happens when you add `#harule { display: none; }` ?

Comment: @KishoreSahas Where should I add that? To the div on the #harule data file? Each person has their own file inside /about/allPeople. These are then included using php.

Comment: you can try adding it inside a new style tag in head

Comment: Could the style tag be inside of the persons file? Refer to previous comment.

Comment: yes , of course just put it before you tab's element .

Comment: Ok, I will try that right now and tell you the result.

Comment: @KishoreSahas Ok, so I did that and it solves the problem, but now clicking on the harule tab does nothing

Comment: is it possible for you to share your source code ?, your page source

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post with the code

Comment: can you also try this `<style id="tempStyle">#harule{display:none;}</style>
         //tab code goes here 
        <script>document.getElementById("tempStyle").remove()</script>`

Comment: This solved the second issue, but now you see it appear in the beginning again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95851/discussion-between-kishoresahas-and-philippos-slicher).

Comment: change the scripts alone to `<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { document.getElementById("tempStyle").remove(); });</script>`

Comment: just saw ur website there is a typo, change id `tempStyle:` to  `tempStyle`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that an I changed it. Still same issue though, @KishoreSahas

Answer (score 0):

It is because the tab is constructed on page ready and the elements are created are while page render (ie before tab)

As the MDL scripts are responsible for generating the tabs, this could be only achievable with a work around

Add this style and script tag to your source .

```js
        <style id="tempStyle">#harule{display:none;}</style>
         //tab code goes here 
        <script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
                   setTimeout(function (e) {
                      document.getElementById("tempStyle").remove();
                   }, 1000);
                });</script>
```

Comment: This sort of solved the issue. You don't see it on page load, and it does appear when tab is clicked. BUT on page load, you see the original issue, only its invisible. It's like an empty div appeared and then got deleted.

Comment: now the next tabs are loading in that place , just append the other divs also to your style `<style id="tempStyle">#harule,#bananatechtips,#lerno1{display:none;}</style>`